# Container (with column in it) doesn't adjust to the content inside flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create something like a review card that will adapt to the amount of text inside it (change the height). However, for some reason the container that is created much larger and I don't understand why

What I get:

[image: pic of what i get]

What I wanted:

[image: pic of what i wanted]

My code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String descText =
        "Truly, manuscripts don't burn. Mikhail Bulgakov's works have not been published for a long time, but since the ban was lifted, they have become bestsellers!";

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: press,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 27,
                          backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              review.getReviewAuthor().getProfileImageUrl(),
                            ),
                            maxRadius: 25,
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(width: 15),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                        review.getReviewAuthor().getName(),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.star_border_rounded,
                      color: primaryColor,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      review.getReviewRating().toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              descText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried to solve my problem through the stack and fix the widget positions using (Positioned), but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` in your `Column`

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: press,
      child: Container(
        ...
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min //  add this line
          children: [...]
         )
      )
);
```

Output:

[image]